# Change the sample rate of returned data in Google Cloud Metrics?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metrics

The Google Metrics I am tracking has a sample rate of 1 every 60 seconds.  When I query the api, is it possible to ask for a different rate to be returned?  For example, I would like to get 1 data point per 15 minutes instead of 1 per 60 seconds.

Reading the documentation, I could not find a filter that would accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

For predefined [Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp), you can grep the list for "Sampled every" to determine the frequency of metric collection. In your example, your metric is "Sampled every 60 seconds".

You cannot change the frequency of data collection for predefined metrics for [monitored resource types](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources), but you can influence how you query the time-series that are produced. This involves applying some function to the underlying data to create a new time-series.

In your case, to reduce the granularity of your once-per-minute time-series  data to once-per-15-minute time-series, you will need to determine how to sample the underlying data.

<strike>I think you can't (!?) literally sample the time-series to every 15th value (I may be wrong)</strike>

> **NOTE** I was wrong. See "next older" (`ALIGN_NEXT_OLDER`) below.

You will need to decide upon a statistical function that represents a 15-minute window (bucket) of data, e.g. min, max, mean etc.  You can extract a single, final value from a bucket using "next older" (`ALIGN_NEXT_OLDER`). List of [Aligners](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#Aligner).

The documentation does a good job of explaining this [alignment](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/aggregation#alignment-intro)

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.